# Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int' using addition

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I fix the error? the error appears on OrderNumber + AddOrderNumber and on line OrderNumber = sqlCmd1.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

Thanks here is the code:

```
  int AddOrderNumber = 1;
        int OrderNumber;


        TextBox1.Text = OrderNumber + AddOrderNumber;
        TextBox2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");
        TextBox3.Text = (string)Session["name"];


        using (SqlConnection con6 = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString))
        {

            //Grab Customer #
            using (SqlCommand sqlCmd1 = new SqlCommand { CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 [OrderNumber] FROM [datarep].[dbo].[OrderHeader] Order By [OrderNumber] DESC", Connection = con6 })
            {
                con6.Open();
                object result = sqlCmd1.ExecuteScalar();

                if (result != null)
                {
                    OrderNumber = sqlCmd1.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

                }
                else
                {

                }
                con6.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Just read what your compiler tells you. The error tells you exactly all you need to know in this case.

Comment: is the OrderNumber stored as a number or a string in the database? and if you are planning to do math on it, why use `.ToString()` at all?

Comment: its stored as an int

Comment: just remove the `.ToString()` from the `ExecuteScalar()`.  there is no reason to convert the value from the database at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
OrderNumber = sqlCmd1.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

`OrderNumber` is of type `int` and you're trying to pass in a `string` to that variable. Do a `Convert.ToInt32` on `sqlCmd1.ExecuteScalar().ToString()`.

```
OrderNumber = Convert.ToInt32(sqlCmd1.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```